# Tabular 2016 - DAX measure: How to reference a calculation alias for aggregation

Tags: dax, sql-server-2016, tabular

I want a total of a sum of all values which have expiry dates greater than the current context date, for each date. 
Code:

```
EVALUATE(
    VAR v = ADDCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'Dates Expiry',
                [Year]
            ),'Dates Expiry'[Year] <> BLANK()
        ) ,"X", CALCULATE(SUM('LM Property Tenant Unit'[CurrentRent]), FILTER(ALL('LM Property Tenant Unit'), 'LM Property Tenant Unit'[ExpiryYear] > 'Dates Expiry'[Year]))
    )
    RETURN(v)
)
```

The result of my DAX is 2 columns; year and value:

- **Dates Expiry[Year]**    **[X]**
- 2018  68917213.56
- 2019  68399351.84
- 2020  67828645.39

What I want to do now to is reference column "X" and sum the list of values to get a total.

1. I have tried referencing the column in another summarize but the sum
   function want a table context.

Is there a way to reference "X" and aggregate to a single value?

Comment: You have two options, create a calculated table (now possible in SSAS 2016) which you can reference from any query. Or create a new query without summarizing by year.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this next. Check out what I determined my answer was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**:

In the end I discovered the DAX GROUPBY function which allows one to reference the result set that was internally defined and apply further calculations to it:

```
GROUPBY(
        FILTER(FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'Dates Expiry',
                [Year]
                ,"X", CALCULATE(SUM('LM Property Tenant Unit'[CurrentRent]),
                 FILTER(FILTER(ALL('LM Property Tenant Unit'), 'LM Property Tenant Unit'[ExpiryYear] > 'Dates Expiry'[Year]), 'LM Property Tenant Unit'[CommenceDate] < TODAY()))
            ),'Dates Expiry'[Year] <> BLANK()), AND('Dates Expiry'[Year] > YEAR(TODAY()), 'Dates Expiry'[Year] < YEAR(TODAY())+16)
        )
        , "SX", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), [X])
    )
```